# i want to show a template before tabs

Tags: magento2, phtml

I want to show a template just before all tabs but it's not showing.

my code on file `catalog_product_view.xml` :

```
       <referenceContainer name="product.info.detailed">
            <block before="product.info.detailed" name="srapsware_product_related" cacheable="true" template="Srapsware_RelatedProductsUpSellsCrossSells::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Related</argument>
            <argument name="perline" xsi:type="number">6</argument>
            <argument name="maxnum" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: what is your xml file name?

Comment: @Ranganathan file name is catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

can u please try below code :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block before="product.info.details" name="srapsware_product_related" cacheable="true" template="Srapsware_RelatedProductsUpSellsCrossSells::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Related</argument>
                    <argument name="perline" xsi:type="number">6</argument>
                    <argument name="maxnum" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

OR:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block before="-" name="srapsware_product_related" cacheable="true" template="Srapsware_RelatedProductsUpSellsCrossSells::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Related</argument>
                    <argument name="perline" xsi:type="number">6</argument>
                    <argument name="maxnum" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution, Working in my env

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.info.media" name="srapsware_product_related" cacheable="true" template="Srapsware_RelatedProductsUpSellsCrossSells::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Related</argument>
                <argument name="perline" xsi:type="number">6</argument>
                <argument name="maxnum" xsi:type="number">12</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: main is showing below main so it showing right side i am want just before tabs

Comment: Pls check now. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom-tab" template="Magento_Catalog::file.phtml"
                   group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">attributte_title</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">400</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceBlock>
```